# ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week

Tags: oracle

```
    SQL> create or replace procedure test ( newcol in varchar2,fld_timestamp out timestamp ) as 
      2  begin
      3  fld_timestamp := to_timestamp_tz('newcol','DAY Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZD YYYY');
      4  end;
      5  /

    Procedure created.

    SQL> declare
     2  fld_timestamp timestamp;
     3  begin
     4  test('WEDNESDAY Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016',fld_timestamp);
     5  end;
     6  /
    declare
   *
   ERROR at line 1:
   ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week
   ORA-06512: at "SANPALLE.TEST", line 3
   ORA-06512: at line 4
```

I have created a procedure named test to convert the char data into timestamp . The input i am giving to procedure is in correct format but i still getting "not valid day of the week" , can someone please tell me where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `'` quotes on `'newcol'`. Also use `TZR` instead of `TZD` in the format.

It should be like this:

```
3  fld_timestamp := to_timestamp_tz(newcol,'DAY Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZR YYYY');
```

Comment: It also needs to be TZR not TZD if the OP is passing in `EST`. And maybe worth mentioning that DAY is NLS-sensitive.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I agree. Edited.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole . Even with TZD it worked .Please see below                              SQL> create or replace procedure test ( newcol in varchar2,fld_timestamp out timestamp ) as
  2  begin
  3  fld_timestamp := to_timestamp_tz(newcol,'Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZD YYYY');
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2  fld_timestamp timestamp;
  3  begin
  4  test('Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016',fld_timestamp);
  5  dbms_output.put_line(fld_timestamp);
  6  end;
  7  /
13-JAN-16 04.29.00.000000 PM

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

Comment: @newbee - interesting, I get ORA-01857: not a valid time zone with TZD and EST. Maybe that's a version difference. That code isn't really very readable or useful in a comment though *8-)

Comment: SQL> create or replace procedure test ( newcol in varchar2,fld_timestamp out timestamp ) as 
       2 begin 
       3 fld_timestamp := to_timestamp_tz(newcol,'Dy Mon DD hh24:mi:ss TZD YYYY'); 
       4 end; 
       5 /

       Procedure created.                                                                           SQL> declare 
       2 fld_timestamp timestamp; 
3 begin 
       4 test('Wed Jan 13 16:29:00 EST 2016',fld_timestamp);
5 dbms_output.put_line(fld_timestamp); 
6 end;
       7 / 13-JAN-16 04.29.00.000000 PM 
       PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.